# Why is there a border at the top of my html page

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML, having picked it up to work with electron. I have created my initial screen however I cannot figure out why there is a bar at the top of the screen, i.e. the title & selection are not at the top.

```css
    .menu-selector ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #c4c4c4;
     text-align:center;
     position: fixed;
     overflow: auto;
    }


    #myList a{
      display: block;
      color: #000;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-top: 20%;
      padding-bottom: 20%;
    }

    #myList : last-child {
     border-bottom: none;
    }


    #myList a:hover:not(.active) {
     background-color: #555;
     color: white;
    }

    #myList a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    body {background-color: #828c9b;}

    .title {
     width = 40%;
     height = 40%;
     padding-left: 38%;
     background-color: #254982;
     display: block;
     border-color: #254982;
    }


    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link class="menu-bar" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
   <link class="container" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menu.css">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Cipher Program</title>
    <style>
     body {margin: 0; padding-top: 0; border-top: 0}

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div class="menu-selector">
   <ul>
     <li id="myList"><a class="active" href="index.html"> Menu </a></li>
     <li id="myList"><a href="ceaser.html">Ceaser Cipher</a></li>
     <li id="myList"><a href="vernam.html">Vernam Cipher </a></li>
     <li id="myList"><a href="frequency.html">Frequency Analysis</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>


   <!-- Page Content -->
   <div class="title">
    <h1> Welcome to Cipher Program </h1>

   </div>

   <div class="ceaser">
    <h2>Menu </h2>
    
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: h1 tag is having default margin added by browsers by default. add margin:0 to h1 element. that should fix the issue. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your h1 CSS as follows:

```
h1 {
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 0;
}
```

The problem is with the user agent stylesheet that automatically assigns some margin to your h1.

What you should do in your CSS files is to have a boilerplate so-called [CSS Reset](https://cssreset.com/) at the beginning of you CSS file to make sure that your html looks the same across all browsers and then style the margin etc. as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `h1` has a margin. Remove it by setting `margin: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<h>` tags have margin as deafult.

for solve

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

and I suggest you investigate 'reset css'

Answer (score 0):

When you are using position absolute or fixed, you must define a top attribute .
please define "top" on ".menu-selector ul" like this :

```
.menu-selector ul {
    top: 0;


    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
```